# Cassandra Read TimeOut during paging query

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have 2 cassandra node with replica_factor=2. I am trying to run **select().all()** from my code and i used **setFetchSize(50000)**. When i start iterating result after some time it throw readTimeOutException **Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)**. Could any one please give me some suggestion?

**I am creating cluster using below code**

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        poolingOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 52)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 80)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 500);

    SocketOptions socketOption = new SocketOptions();
    socketOption.setReadTimeoutMillis(600000)
    .setReceiveBufferSize(1024*512)
    .setSendBufferSize(1024*512)
    .setKeepAlive(true).setConnectTimeoutMillis(1800000);

    cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(cassandraHosts.get("HOST_1"), cassandraHosts.get("HOST_2"))
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .withPort(cassandraPort)
            .withSocketOptions(socketOption)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())).build();
    Session session = cluster.connect(cassandraDB);
```

- Cassandra version: 2.2.1
- Java 7
- Is there any other way to execute select all query without read time out exception

Comment: Try a much smaller fetch-size.

Comment: @Ralf it will take longer time if i reduce fetchSize because my query return almost 24 million rows. And this exception happing after fetching 10-15 pages for give query i.e after processing 750000 rows i got this exception

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer?